# increment progress bar inside for loop in c++ Qt

Tags: qt, qprogressbar

I am new in Qt , i want to show some progress in progress bar in side a for loop,
progress bar should show progress  from 0 to 100
How to do this ,plz help thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation (e.g. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprogressbar.html)

> A progress bar is used to give the user an indication of the progress of an operation [...]
>
> You can specify the minimum and maximum number of steps with setMinimum() and setMaximum. The current number of steps is set with setValue().

So what you need is to construct a `QProgressBar` object, specify what the minimum and maximum should be and then call `setValue(int value)` to make it progress.

For your case:

```
QProgressBar progressBar;
progressBar.setMinimum(0);
progressBar.setMaximum(100);
// or as alternative to the two above, you could call
// progressBar.setRange(0,100);

for( int i = 0; i <100; ++i ) {
   progressBar.setValue(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QProgressBar bar;

for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    bar.setValue(i);
}
```